# Representation of heat kernel in general domains

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation, semigroups-of-operators

I'm looking for results on the representation of the heat kernel in general domains. If $e^{-\Delta_{\Omega} t}$ denotes the heat semigroup in $\Omega$, we have to
$$ (e^{-\Delta_{\Omega} t}f)(x) = \int_{\Omega}K_{\Omega}(x,y,t)f(y)dy $$
where $K_{\Omega}: \Omega \times \Omega \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ is a $C^{\infty}-$function called heat kernel. In the case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$,$K_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x,y,t) = K(x-y,t), $ where
$$K(z,t) = \dfrac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/4t}.$$
My question is, if $\Omega$ is not equal to all $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it possible in general to represent the function $K_{\Omega}$? If possible, what is the representation? Can you point me to articles or books?

[Here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00028-015-0305-3.pdf) I found a representation, for when the domain is of type $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_i>0 \mbox{ for } I=1,\cdots , n \}$. But what happens for example in a $\mathbb{R}^n$ cone?

Comment: For $K_\Omega$ there is a very general construction by Hidehiko Yamabe: this construction allows also for the construction of very general reproducing kernels for the Laplace operator (which, in case $\Omega$ had sufficiently smooth boundaries is the Green operator for the Dirichlet problem of the given domain). However, the construction is highly implicit as it is based on infinite iteration of the heat kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference!